# Why is "door" pronounced with an "o" sound and not a "u"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Why is *door* pronounced as in 'o' not as in 'u' ?

Comment: Related: [Written English Vowels are Odd](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235/written-english-vowels-are-odd)

Comment: A better question might be, why is the word pronounced *dôr* spelled with two Os?  I think a big chunk of "why" questions about language are unanswerable.

Comment: "Dearest creature in creation, study English pronunciation ...". Pronunciation changed over time, while spelling remained the same.

Comment: There is already a word *dour* that's pronounced like that.  It would be confusing!

Comment: @z7sg: you mean like "read" and "red"? Or perhaps "read" and "reed"? :-)

Comment: Door is pronounced 'dur' - at least were 'r come from!

Comment: An example from a related language: in Dutch, the word spelled "door" (by) is pronounced nearly the same way as in English.

Comment: I pronounce it like a 'u'.

Comment: Related post on Linguistics SE: [“oo” in “poor”, “door” and “doom”](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/14517/oo-in-poor-door-and-doom)

Answer (score 5):

Because **door** is one of those words that have two O's because people thought that would make the O sound *longer*. Meaning longer in duration. In Old English the word was spelled *dor* with a long O. There was no character to write that kind of long O, so they figured the double O would make people hold the duration longer. Maybe it worked for a time, but obviously it failed somewhere over the past 1,000 years.

Comment: All of the old words spelled with "oo" originally were pronounced with a long [o:] sound, but were raised to [u:] during the [Great Vowel Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift).  This answer doesn't address the central issue of why the vowel was raised in e.g. "fool" and "room" (and most others) but not in "door" (or "poor" in some dialects).

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Also note *floor*, etc., but I take your point. My response also doesn't explain *flood* and other variations.

Comment: Also *hood*, which is yet another vowel: /ʊ/ (while *flood* is /ʌ/).

Answer (score 0):

It comes from middle english *dore*. The pronunciation of the word didn't change so much, but as spelling rules changed, it's spelling naturally had to change.

There are other words that are formed in a similar way from middle english spelling; more -> moor, povre -> poor.

Answer (score -2):

Short Answer: There are two sounds for "oo". One is more like "Ô" and the other is the longer sound.