# Reason for ambiguous pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why do written English vowels differ from other Latin-based orthographies?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235/why-do-written-english-vowels-differ-from-other-latin-based-orthographies)

I noticed that in English some words that have the same letters (except for the first), have a different pronunciation, like:

> bat (short a)
>
> bet (same sound but shorter)
>
> let (same sound)

or

> me
> thee
> fee

or

> dog (long o)
> hot (short o)

Is there a (historical?) reason for it?

Comment: The words *bat* and *bet* do not have the same vowel. The first is [æ] while the second is [ɛ].

Comment: @FumbleFingers actually it's not a duplicate, mine is ambiguous, the other question seems not to be.

Comment: @JSBangs Yes you are right in that ...

Comment: @Michel Keijzers: If the specific thing you want to know isn't covered by nohat's answer to the earlier question, you should prompt him with a comment there. I really don't think there's any special "historical" reason relevant to your question that both isn't, and *shouldn't* be covered there.

Comment: What the heck is a long o or short o in *dog*  /dɔg/ and *hot*  /hɒt/?  I guess southerners might lengthen the *dog* vowel into /dɔːg/ as in *caught*, but that’s still not a version of /ɒ/.  This shows why it’s futile to talk about these things without ɪᴘᴀ. For a *really swell time*, [try these](http://www.soundcomparisons.com/).

Comment: @tchrist, I believe he means a "long short o", and a "short short o"

Comment: This is silly. English **letters** have almost nothing to do with English pronunciation, and attempting to explain that they do is a waste of time and effort. Better go look at the GVS, as FF suggests.

Comment: @tchrist: A swell time indeed! but they didn't have "tsk".

Comment: I think I have to read more about all this (all vowels and the 18 sounds mentioned above).